# When clicking on a link under the title bar menu I get the error "postBodyCol2"

Tags: craft2

I have migrated a site from Cpanel to Plesk and when I click on one for the sub menus I get the error:

When clicking on a link under the title bar menu I get the error:
Internal Server Error
Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "postBodyCol2".

I cannot create new entries in the menu bar either nor remove thing for there either.

Comment: What version of PHP is the site running?

Comment: PHP 7.0. This was an old website and it seemed that when the old developer gave me the website file some was missing. The method postBodyCol2 was no longer there so I had to recreate it. Once this had been done the issue was fixed. Thanks for you help :)